# select2 v4 programmatically remove a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to remove a select2 multiselect `<li>` element that was previously selected but I have a problem - fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/64nxhLc1/44/

What I'm doing basically is this:

```
   $("button").click(function() {
      $("li-i-want-removed").remove();
    });
```

This does remove the inner tag, but the next time I select something else, I get the previous filled automatically.

A gets removed, then when selecting B, A pops right back in.
I want to trigger the `select2:unselect` event somehow but i'm clueless as to how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work , remove the li genrated `select2` and also set `selected` to `false` to the select tag :

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myselect').select2({
        placeholder: "select option",
        tags:true
    });
});

$("button").click(function() {
   // remove the li node at first 
   $("#myselect").next(".select2").find("li[title='A']").remove();
   // set the select with value A to unselected
   $("#myselect").find("option[value='A']").prop("selected",false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<button>
remove A
</button>

<div style="margin:30px; height:400px;">


<select id="myselect" multiple = "multiple" style="min-width:300px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value='A'>A</option>
  <option value='B'>B</option>
  <option value='C'>C</option>
</select>

</div>
```

You can also use the change event , so unselect first the value then trigger the `change`that removes the li automaticly from the select :

see below snippet :

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myselect').select2({
        placeholder: "select option",
        tags:true
    });
});

$("button").click(function() {
   // set the select with value A to unselected
   $("#myselect").find("option[value='A']").prop("selected",false);
   $("#myselect").trigger("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<button>
remove A
</button>

<div style="margin:30px; height:400px;">


<select id="myselect" multiple = "multiple" style="min-width:300px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value='A'>A</option>
  <option value='B'>B</option>
  <option value='C'>C</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: this should resove your issue

Comment: This is a very nice solution, it makes complete sense, just tested it and it works - which is perfect. It might be a bit of a stretch but do you have any idea if I could trigger this "select2:unselect" event from clicking the button? I wanted to basically replicate the behavior of clicking the close element on the tag. Your solution is perfectly usable but just as mind-training. :x

Comment: Great :D , please note that `select2:unselect` is an event that is fired after  unselecting a value note before so you cant use it to remove a selected item ,   but you can use the change event that as descriebd in my second snippet :) 
See updated answer